# Generate thumbnail images from open tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if there is a common technique to generate thumbnails from open tabs or from some page. Researched for a while but I didn't came up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

It captures the visible area of the active tab and return an image in data-URL form.

Not exactly what you're looking for, but may be it worth try.

Comment: I've already seen that, but was looking for the existence of maybe a easier, less manual way of doing it, maybe with a native library of some sort (that i've though chrome would have). But i think this will do, thanks!